# Error creating opengl context with SDL ( BadMatch )

Tags: c++, opengl

This code was working, but stopped working after a refactor, and only on one computer, with a NVidia graphics card.

I've narrowed it down to this:

This code works:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );

SDL_Window *NewSDLWindowHandle = SDL_CreateWindow ( "SDL invisible window", 0, 0, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN );
if ( NewSDLWindowHandle == NULL )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to create SDL window. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
    }

ContextHandle = SDL_GL_CreateContext ( NewSDLWindowHandle );
if ( ContextHandle == NULL )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to create opengl context. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    SDL_DestroyWindow ( NewSDLWindowHandle );
    ContextHandle = NULL;
    return false;
    }

if ( SDL_GL_MakeCurrent ( NewSDLWindowHandle, ContextHandle ) != 0 )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to activate opengl context. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    SDL_DestroyWindow ( NewSDLWindowHandle );
    ContextHandle = NULL;
    return false;
    }


#ifdef GRAPHICS_BACKEND_USE_GLEW
#ifdef __APPLE__
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
#endif
glewInit();
#endif
NewSDLWindowHandle = SDL_CreateWindow ( "SDL opengl window window", 0, 0, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
if ( NewSDLWindowHandle == NULL )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to create SDL window. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
    }
```

Basically I create an invisible window, just to initialize an opengl context, get version, check extensions, etc etc... Then I create the actual window that I'm going to use..
Now this new version, for some reason, does not work:

```
SDL_Window *NewSDLWindowHandle = SDL_CreateWindow ( "SDL opengl window window", 0, 0, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
if ( NewSDLWindowHandle == NULL )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to create SDL window. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    return NULL;
    }

SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );

/*    SDL_Window *NewSDLWindowHandle = SDL_CreateWindow ( "SDL invisible window", 0, 0, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN );
if ( NewSDLWindowHandle == NULL )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to create SDL window. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
    }*/

ContextHandle = SDL_GL_CreateContext ( NewSDLWindowHandle );
if ( ContextHandle == NULL )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to create opengl context. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    SDL_DestroyWindow ( NewSDLWindowHandle );
    ContextHandle = NULL;
    return false;
    }

if ( SDL_GL_MakeCurrent ( NewSDLWindowHandle, ContextHandle ) != 0 )
    {
    LOG_ERROR ( "Unable to activate opengl context. \"%s\"", SDL_GetError() );
    SDL_DestroyWindow ( NewSDLWindowHandle );
    ContextHandle = NULL;
    return false;
    }
```

You can see that basically all I did was not create the invisible window, and simply create the desired one, and then create an opengl context.
It fails on the check after SDL_GL_CreateContext with "Could not make GL context current: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)"

So, in the final version ( which also works ) I simply moved the SDL_GL_SetAttribute cals to before the SDL_CreateWindow, and created the window and it works. Can anyone explain to me why? Why does it matter that I set opengl attributes for a context I have not created before or after I create a window that is still not associated with OpenGL ?

Comment: AFAIK, in X11 the window must be shown when the context is made current.

Comment: It shouldn't have to be. You can perfectly well create a hidden opengl window just to render something without wanting to display it, maybe for some heavy animation rendering, computer-made movie, etc...